Infer dependent non-type template parameters
A class is templated on an array which represents a particular configuration for the class. This allows the configuration to be checked at compile time. Here is a complete simplistic example:
#include <array>

template<std::size_t config_size, const std::array<int, config_size>& config>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    static constexpr bool configIsValid() ;
};

template<std::size_t config_size, const std::array<int, config_size>& config>
MyClass<config_size, config>::MyClass()
{
    static_assert(configIsValid());
}

template<std::size_t config_size, const std::array<int, config_size>& config>
constexpr bool MyClass<config_size, config>::configIsValid()
{
    return (config.size() > 3);
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr std::array<int, 4> valid_config{1,2,3,4};
    MyClass<4, valid_config> a;
    
    static constexpr std::array<int, 3> invalid_config{5,6,7};
    // MyClass<3, invalid_config> b; // This will fail to compile

    return 0;
}

This is OK, but the first template argument can be inferred from the second, so I would prefer to write:
MyClass<config> m;
Instead of:
MyClass<config_size, config> m;
Is there any way to do this?
The array could possibly be wrapped, but I'm not able to use a different container.

"I'm not able to use a different container" -- Not able to use, or must not support? For example, what should happen if someone tried to use a std::deque as the config object? Is it required that this be a compile-time error? If not, then this could be a duplicate of Template Parameter with implicit array size ,

The only way this can be achieved with templates is to use auto type:
template<const auto& config>
class MyClass

and so on. Here is link to complete code: https://godbolt.org/z/j6EKW9aff
Other approach is to use macro for template parameters, like this:
#define CONFIG_PARAMS(a) a.size(), a

MyClass<CONFIG_PARAMS(valid_config)> a;


You don't have to change the class definition, you could just add an alias which does the transformation https://godbolt.org/z/aTTezKEcj

I think the answer to the question you posed is "no, you can't" - the type of a non-type template parameter has to be specified.
There are some alternative approaches:
In C++20 you can write a consteval function which returns an instance of the correct type.
template<typename C>
consteval auto deduceMyClass(C& config) {
  // Unnecessary but possible: static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::array<int, config.size()>, C>);
  return MyClass<config.size(), config>{};
}

In C++17 (possibly also 14 and 11, my memory is hazy) you can use a deduction guide for this at the price of making the config reference a constructor argument rather than a template parameter.

"the type of a non-type template parameter has to be specified." Not with auto
